# How to authenticate users accesing my bluemix app?

Tags: web, cloud, ibm-cloud

Any option available to authenticate users accessing my app on bluemix URL?

I want to make a set of audience to use my bluemix URL?Any leads how to implement this?

Comment: Do you want them to use your app or to manage your app in bluemix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to your app overview page and click on edit routes. You would see enable app authentication property which by default is OFF. Make that to "ON". After that you need to add member to your organisation who would have access to your app.

Attaching a sample screenshot for your help : [image: authentication]

Answer (score 1):

The SSO service is the way to go if all the users accessing your application have an IBM ID. In some cases we have used a more custom api key approach or even pre-exchanged certificates for which you would need to add some code for.

Answer (score 1):

In bluemix you can add people to your organization, once you do that they will be able to manage your app, delete, restart, stop, etc.

Take in mind that you are the one who pay for the app so if they add memory or instances you will be charged for those expenses.

In order to add people to your organization:

1. Login to https://ace.ng.bluemix.net
2. Click on 'MANAGE ORGANIZATIONS'
    
   [image]
3. Add/invite a bluemix user to manage your app

Answer (score 1):

Complete documentation on using the OAuth authentication service with the SSO service in BLuemix is available here:  https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted

Examples and client code also:
 https://hub.jazz.net/project/bluemixsso/SingleSignOnSampleClient/overview. The sample application can help you write your own client application to leverage the IBM Single Sign On for Bluemix service's capabilities. You can create your own copy of the code in your own DevOps JazzHub account as well, and then build it and then deploy it to your own IBM Bluemix space.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try single sign on authentication provided by bluemix.

Below is the getting started link with this:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted

You can get various option to authenticate users(via fb,google) etc and apply in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this link, about Single Sign On.

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SingleSignOn/index.html#sso_gettingstarted

I hope this help you.

Good luck!